# Having an ampersand in a querystring parameter

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm a bit new to javascript and I'm having a minor problem:

I'm trying to redirect to a page (which then performs a redirect) in javascript. I'm setting the `window.location` like so:

```
window.location = "./RedirectPage.aspx?ReturnUrl=page.aspx?key=val&amp;key2=val2";
```

Now, on RedirectPage.aspx when it's trying to redirect to the page that I passed in as the ReturnUrl, it is parsing key2=val2 as being another querystring parameter for RedirectPage instead of the ReturnUrl.

It makes sense that it does that, but that's not what I am trying to do... any idea how I might solve this?

Comment: Your ampersands have been encoded somewhere. You'll need to examine where the encoding is happening.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want to URL encode the ReturnUrl querystring.

```
window.location = "./RedirectPage.aspx?ReturnUrl="+encodeURIComponent("page.aspx?key=val&amp;key2=val2");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
window.location = "./RedirectPage.aspx?"+encodeURIComponent("ReturnUrl=page.aspx?key=val&key2=val2")
```

You need to escape the ampersand (for use in a query string).

Comment: So close. As it turned out, ReturnUrl= needed to be outside of the encodeURIComponent. +1 to both you and Theron, but his was more correct. Thank you.